# AP Calculus Limits Problem

Tags: calculus

Why for the geometric proof of the limit as $\frac{sinx}{x}\ $ as x approaches zero, why is the range for the x values between $-\frac{π}{2} < x < \frac{π}{2} \ $

Surely it is also valid for this $-\frac{π}{2} ≤ x ≤ \frac{π}{2} \ $ and for the function not being valid at x = 0

Comment: I think it is for $0<x\le\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: The function *at* zero has almost nothing to do with the *limit* of the function as it *approaches* zero, so it not being valid at zero is irrelevant.  As for increasing the range to include $\pi/2$... sure... you could also decrease the range to $\pi/4$ as well or change the range to *literally anything* so long as it contains a "*neighborhood*" surrounding zero since all that matters are the values "close" to zero.

Comment: @Physor we need to consider not only the limit from the right but also the limit from the left as well.  A proof which considers only $0<x<\epsilon$ (*for whatever epsilon greater than zero*) is incomplete.

Comment: The proof involves the limit $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ (then through symmetry, $\to0^-$).  This is nowhere near $\pi/2$ (at which $\tan$ is undefined, and is a function used in the proof).

Comment: @JMoravitz, is this $0<|x|\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ better ?